# How to list all processes/services running on different ports

Tags: localhost, port

Is there a command that lists all the services that are running on different ports of localhost?

In my case, when I'm working on an Angular app, I may run it on localhost:4200, a React app on localhost:3000 and a Redis server on localhost:6379, etc.

Is there a way of knowing if these are running and how can I kill/stop them?

Comment: Have you tried to look that up using Google? That directly lists stuff like https://superuser.com/questions/529830/get-a-list-of-open-ports-in-linux

Comment: I did search for some time, I think I missed the keyword "Open ports".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows use `netstat -nba | FINDSTR "LISTEN"` to get a list of processes (Pids) listening on a port

if you need to find a specific port, then pipe it through findstr twice 
`netstat -nba | FINDSTR "LISTEN" | FINDSTR "3000"`

In powershell you can then use Stop-Process CMDlet with the Id option to stop the process

```
Stop-Process -Id 1234
```

if you want to do it all in one powershell command, you can go with

```
Stop-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 3000).OwningProcess -Force
```

or

```
Stop-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 6379).OwningProcess -Force
```

for redis

Comment: This isn't working for me. It's not doing anything.

Comment: on windows? What about just netstat -ba

Comment: Yeah, must be adminisrtrator

Comment: How can know the name or any other detail of the processes along with their ports?

Comment: you can get more info with `Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 6379).OwningProcess`

Comment: I don't know if this changed in newer windows versions, or it was just an oversight, but you also need to specify the -o flag to get the PID.
so that would be: `netstat -nbao | FINDSTR "LISTEN"`

Answer (score 9):

Which operating system are you using? The answer may differ depending on the type of the operating system, including different distributions.

For example, on some Linux distributions I'd rather use `ss -nltp`.

Example:

```
$ ss -nltp
State      Recv-Q Send-Q   Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port
LISTEN     0      128                  *:22                       *:*   
LISTEN     0      10           127.0.0.1:25                       *:*   
LISTEN     0      128                 :::111                     :::*   
LISTEN     0      50                  :::8080                    :::*   
LISTEN     0      128                 :::22                      :::*
```

Explained:

`-n, --numeric       don't resolve service names` (google.com --> 1.2.3.4)

`-l, --listening     display listening sockets` (just the ports you're listening at)

`-p, --processes     show process using socket` (include sub processes locking sockets)

`-t, --tcp           display only TCP sockets`

A more general command would be `netstat`.

Example: `$ netstat -nl`

Please check the [manual of `ss`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ss.8.html) for more information.

---

Edit: Since you said you were using Windows, you can use this to list all the relevant processes (-n == numeric, -a == all, -o == show process id, -p TCP == show TCP only):

`netstat -nao -p TCP`

**Last column would be the process ID**, you can use `taskkill` to kill the process:

`taskkill /F /PID <PID>`

Where `/F` says forcefully kill and `/PID` indicates the next value is the process ID.

Comment: The following lets you select processes by their name or the port they're using and send [SIGTERM](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html) to them: `kill $(ss -nap | fzf | grep -oP 'pid=\K[^,]+')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use batch(cmd.exe) for this task

```
::List processes
@Tasklist.exe

::List services
Sc.exe Query Type= service

::Stop a process 
Taskkill.exe /im "Image name of a task.exe"


::Stop a service
@%__APPDIR__%Net.exe Stop "Service name"

::Start a service
@%__APPDIR__%Net.exe Start "Service name"
```

## To execute these bat files:

- Open notepad and copy one of the codes of them for the task specified.
- Save it as a file with .bat extension.
- Open cmd.exe and drag and drop the bat file and execute it.

Comment: A simple command like MikNiller's answer seems better. Are there any differences in the result of using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try following command :

```
sudo netstat -ltnp
```

The above command gives netstat information based on the following features:

```
l: display only listening sockets 
t: display tcp connection 
n: display addresses in a numerical form 
p: display process ID/ Program name
```

Your output should look something like :

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1784/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9031/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1504/beam.smp   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1798/postgres   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7070            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1245/anydesk    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:70              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1803/nginx -g daemo
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1504/beam.smp   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1476/mongod     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1739/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1683/redis-server 1
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33485         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5582/chrome --type=
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4369            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1736/epmd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2435/teamviewerd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:21460         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15337/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4671/dnsmasq    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1784/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      9031/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:5563          :::*                    LISTEN      15337/node      
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      1504/beam.smp   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2532/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::4369                 :::*                    LISTEN      1736/epmd
```